# How can we give access of "Domain" sObject to any salesforce User's profile?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have implemented a LWC component which has a button. On Click of this button backend callout is done which is responsible for Microsoft One drive Integration.

But I am facing an error for some custom profile see the screenshot-
[Error Snapshot -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA7Dz.png)

This error says that Domain Object is not accessible.

Can anyone tell me how can we provide "Domain" object access to any profile in Salesforce.